# How do you convert each of your inputs to a float?

Tags: python

> I am writing a program that asks for the starting weight of the yeast
> (in grams) and its final weight. Calculate how many hours you would
> need to leave the loaf to rise to achieve the final weight of yeast.
> Output the result as a whole number of hours.

the formula for the calculations being
**(yeast 1 hr later) =(yeast now) + 0.6 × (yeast now)**

```
counter = 0
start = float(input('start (g): '))
finish = float(input('finish (g): '))
hour = start + 0.6 * start
answer = (round(hour,0))
while counter > finish:
  counter = counter + 1
print(f'The loaf would need to rise for {answer} hours')
```

I am trying to convert the inputs into floats and get the calculations right but I don't understand how

the output should look like this:
[image: demo]

Comment: You already got your variables into float. Consider checking the type by using `print(type(start))`

Comment: Your calculation is wrong... this isnt a programming question but a basic logic question

Comment: look at your funciton again...  (yeast 1 hr later) =(yeast now) + 0.6 × (yeast now). Your calculation the amount of yeast after an hour not how many hours it would take to reach your desired yeast amount

Comment: all you need to do is solve x for your equation finish = start * 1.6^x